# Naming convention for Erlang functions

Tags: function, erlang, naming-conventions

I was trying to create a function name like 5gc_ep_n2 and it gave me a syntax error. What is the exact naming convention for the functions in Erlang?

**updated**: Found this [reference](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html) helps too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function names are atoms, and follow the same rules as atoms.  From [the reference manual](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#atom):

> An atom is to be enclosed in single quotes (') if it does not begin with a lower-case letter or if it contains other characters than alphanumeric characters, underscore (_), or @.

So you can call your function `5gc_ep_n2`, but you'd have to enclose it in single quotes, `'5gc_ep_n2'`, both when defining and calling it.